# What exactly is the "git database"?

Tags: git, nomenclature

In discussions about `git` mentions of the so-called "git database" are not uncommon, but I've never been able to tell (from the context) whether "the git database" refers to the `.git` directory, or to the `.git/objects` directory, or to the `.git/index` file, or something else altogether.

I'm sure that different people, at different times, mean different things by this term, but I'm wondering  if there's anything like an "official" (or at least reasonably authoritative<sup>1</sup>) definition of what the "git database" refers to.

<sub><sup>1</sup> For example, a quotation by Torvalds along the lines of "the git database is xyz" would do for me as an authoritative definition.</sub>

Comment: http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Internals-Git-Objects

Answer (score 0):

OK, for what it's worth, in the initial commit of the `git` project, the program implemented in `init-db.c` basically creates a directory, whose path is, by default, given by the value of the constant `DEFAULT_DB_ENVIRONMENT`.  This constant is defined in `cache.h` as

```
#define DEFAULT_DB_ENVIRONMENT ".dircache/objects"
```

A few commits later, this value gets changed to `".git/objects"`.

So... `.git/objects` is the best candidate I've found for what "the git database" refers to.